# MySQL Copying row from table to table, using PHP at same time

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I know you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

But what if instead of `SELECT a, b, c, d` you need to update those columns as `a, b, c, "string"`

so to put it plainly I want a statement that says:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
// And put  "string" into d
```

UPDATE

So I ran this:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, c, 'string'
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

It selected 3 rows with different entries in 'c' column and it updates 'AnotherTable' by inserting 3 rows all the exact same. They should be different values though...

Comment: you can select the value by such type and it will work.

Comment: The update I posted did actually work, I just forgot to save -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b,"SOME VALE","SOMEVALUE2"
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, $somevar, 'fixed string'
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

However, you should be very careful about injecting $somevar like that. Really you should be using prepared statements, so it would be...

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, :CustomValue, 'fixed string'
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

and CustomValue is set by binding the value to the statement. There are some examples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: so i managed to whittle it down so i dont use a `$var` but the problem is it is inserting the right amount of rows, but they are all duplicates.